# XMLHttpRequest from saved page in hard disk

Tags: java, ajax, flash, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

I saved a page on a hard drive then I opened it and wanted to connect from a saved html file to the server website on the Internet. When trying to do a HTTP request using `XMLHttpRequest` from a file that were loaded in browser manually, it basically fails to do. could you please tell me what should i do? Or is it possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807284/how-to-use-same-xmlhttprequestsame-origin-in-the-saved-page-in-hard-disk
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15791668/connect-local-file-to-a-url-in-the-internet-xmlhttprequest
Same question asked 3 times with different title

Comment: yes ZERO MILE, i think maybe it was not clear for users!

Answer (score 0):

Unless it is a cross domain xmlHttpRequest, it will fail due to same-origin policy.